# Custom aggregate function parallel = safe produces syntax in postgres 13.3

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions, postgresql-13

This causes a syntax error at parallel

```
CREATE AGGREGATE public.first (
        sfunc    = public.first_agg,
        basetype = anyelement,
        stype    = anyelement,
        parallel = safe
);
```

Maybe because of this?
https://www.postgresql-archive.org/reate-parallel-aggregate-td5923553.html

I don't know if there's a syntax change or something and if there is, what the new syntax would be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [the new or the old syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createaggregate.html). There is no `BASETYPE` in the new version and no `PARALLEL` in the old one. In the new syntax you should define the basetype as `arg_data_type`:

```
CREATE AGGREGATE public.first(anyelement) (
        sfunc    = public.first_agg,
        stype    = anyelement,
        parallel = safe
);
```

Comment: Yes, this was very sneaky: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/First/last_(aggregate)